# MS SQL Server Last Inserted ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database all tables are using a common table for Sequence(ID_Table).

TABLE_ID has two fields (Common_ID, Table_Name).

If I insert any record in the table, I have to first insert a record in Table_ID(Auto-increment, Table_name) then use that Auto-increment value in my Other Table.

For example, I want to insert in Table_Products which has fields ID(Common_ID), Product_Name, Product_ID(Auto Increment)

I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_ID (Table_NAME), Values (Table_Products)
```

Get the Inserted ID and use it in Table_Products:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Products (ID, Product_Name, Product_ID(Auto Increment) 
VALUES (ID from TABLE_ID, SomeProduct, Increment)
```

Comment: "In my database all tables are using a common table for Sequence(ID_Table)." - Why?

Comment: @user2345661 - your TABLE_ID contain the id , that must me used in the next insert into table_products right?

Comment: Well it was a firebird Database creatted by someone else which i converted to SQL server.

Comment: are you using storeprocedure for inserting in both table?

Comment: No I am trying to use simple inserts. once i am able to do that than i will learn stored procedures. and I am doing it from C#.

Comment: where you catch the id return by first insert i mean in your c# or php code

Comment: try this SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @ID BIGINT

INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE_ID (Table_NAME) 
SELECT 'Table_Products'

SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_Products (ID, Product_Name)
SELECT @ID, 'SomeProduct'
```

Comment: I think someone playing here. Someone downvoted for me also. :(

Answer (score 6):

Use SCOPE_IDENTITY() after ur insert statementto get the last inserted id.

```
DECLARE @Product_Id int

INSERT INTO TABLE_ID (Table_NAME) VALUES (Table_Products);
SELECT @Product_Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

Insert INTO Table_Products (ID, Product_Name)
VALUES (ID from TABLE_ID, 'SomeProduct')
```

Comment: Several syntax errors (`Table_NAME), Values`), undeclared variables (`@Product_Id`), and specifying an identity column (`Product_ID`) in an insert value list

Comment: @Andomar: He is not going to deploy this code on the production server. I'm just giving him an answer not a script to deploy.

Comment: @Sivakumar Why do you argue instead of correcting these foolish errors?

Comment: @lgor: I couldn't find the approve button to approve your suggested edits. So I just copy and pasted. Don't mistake me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `insert` statement with the `output` clause to generate a new Common_ID.  Using `insert ... select`, you can specify that ID in an insert operation:

```
declare @Common_ID as table(ID int)

insert  Table_ID
        (Table_Name)
output  inserted.Common_ID into @Common_ID
values  ('Table_Products')

insert  Table_Products
        (ID, Product_Name)
select  ID
,       'Some Product'
from    @Common_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Dear friend you have to select id of last record inserted 
and then pass it in another table so bellow code will help you very well

```
Insert INTO TABLE_ID (Table_NAME), Values (Table_Products)
DECLARE @ID int;
set @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 

Insert INTO Table_Products (ID, Product_Name) 
Values (@ID, SomeProduct)
```

this code will solve your problem i define @ID for your last record id and then insert it in your other table

Answer (score 1):

For MySql use `select LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: the question is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers so far declare intermediary variables for `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, but it could be simpler:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE_ID (Table_NAME) VALUES 'Table_Products';

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_Products (ID, Product_Name) VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(),'SomeProduct');
```

Answer (score -1):

You could be also more table-specific using IDENT_CURRENT()

```
Insert INTO TABLE_ID (Table_NAME), Values (Table_Products)

select @NewID=IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE_ID')

Insert INTO Table_Products (ID, Product_Name, Product_ID
Values (@NewID, SomeProduct, Increment)
```

Comment: Using `IDENT_CURRENT` to retrieve the identity you inserted introduces a race condition.

Comment: Most of the answers uses SCOPE_IDENTITY() so I just give him the alternative solution so I used IDENT_CURRENT for that. Does not SCOPE_IDENTITY() virtually has the same scenario although in a more universal context and not table-specific? And how about output? That's very table-specific does it not produce race condition as well? What if after you get the @Common_ID someone inserted a millisecond after that? So, it would not be the last ID?

Comment: `scope_identity()` returns the last ID generated by your session.  And `output` captures the row inserted by your insert statement.  Both are immune to influence from other simultaneous sessions.  But `ident_current()` suffers from race conditions, while `identity()` (without the `scope_`) can be overwritten from a trigger.

Comment: According to Microsoft OUTPUT clause will still give the ID even if there is an error and is it not risky? You may not have a race condition but you could have a case of an 'orphan' records. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: The `output` clause as used above does not use client communication.  In any case, `ident_current` will also return a value if an error occurred during the insert: it will return the id of a previously inserted row.