# How to get a "New Record Id" after inserting a record using ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5, C#, EF5, SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

I want to understand the best approach to get the "New Record Id" once a record has been inserted, given that **the PK is an int32 Identity column**.

My current code is:

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO Table1(Col1,Col2 ) SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM Table1 WHERE Id =   {0}", myOldRecordId);
command = @"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT({0}) AS Current_Identity;";
myNewRecordId = (int)db.ExecuteStoreQuery<decimal>(command, "Table1").First();
```

While the above works, my concern is that someone else could insert a record into the same table at the same time, so the retrieved NewRecordId = correct value + 1.

What is the best way to retrieve the new NewRecordId, once an "INSERT" has been issued via ExecuteStoreCommand?

BTW, I need to use raw DML, for a number of reasons, rather than POCOs via EF.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

The code would change as per my understanding of the advice given:

```
using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()) 
{
   db.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO Table1(Col1,Col2 ) SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM Table1 WHERE Id =   {0}", myOldRecordId);
   command = @"SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY ({0}) AS Current_Identity;";
   myNewRecordId = (int)db.ExecuteStoreQuery<decimal>(command, "Table1").First(); 
   tran.Complete();
}
```

I think I still need to change this, to make the "db.ExecuteStoreCommand" and "db.ExecuteStoreQuery" transaction aware.

EDIT2

After more research, I have discovered this:

```
db.Connection.Open(); //db = EF DBContext
var tran = db.Connection.BeginTransaction();

db.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO Table1(Col1,Col2 ) SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM Table1 WHERE Id =   {0}", myOldRecordId);

command = @"SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY ({0}) AS Current_Identity;";
myNewRecordId = (int)db.ExecuteStoreQuery<decimal>(command, "Table1").First(); 

tran.Commit();
db.Connection.Close();
```

See: [Reference](http://fhtino.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-mix-enity-framework-and-tsql.html)

Is this the best way to get the new ID, without corruption, from other user record inserts?

Actually having read more, this is the old way, and "TransactionScope" is the way to go.

Comment: Try using a `TransasctionScope` and then use scope_identity()
something like `using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOptions)
 { your code to get identity after insert
}`

Comment: Thanks for this. I have not used "TransactionScope". Any chance of a code example. Just slightly confused as to whether the INSERT and the SELECT goes into this or just the SELECT?

Comment: are you using `Entity Framework`? Please do read about the concurrency issues in web applications in general and how `.net` framework handles it in tandem with ORMs like `Entity`... as @Nilesh mentioned one way is to use transactions...Transactions can be handled at the database server level too ...Google is your best friend...

Comment: Both statements need to be part of the scope.
Just sample code, but without EF.
`var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tempforts values('1')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select scope_Identity()",conn);
                var id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }`

Comment: See my EDIT above for my attempted new code which takes in your suggestion.

Comment: Can you confirm that the use of "TransactionScope" with EF commands is the only way to ensure that I get back the correct new Identity value for the inserted record? Thanks

Comment: If someone can provide a code example, within an "Answer", using TransactionScope, then I would be in a position to award points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for writing this in an answer instead of a comment: I think you´re 99% right, as far as I understand it, you should use

```
scope_identity()
```

instead of ident_current, to come to 100%

Comment: Thanks for this. However as per @gurel_kaynak, I am concerned that your answer does not address that this will run within application C# code and not TSQL on the DB Server. Nilesh has introduced some interesting new construct.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer about getting the last insert id [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432893/sql-server-last-inserted-id). You should use this method. And the last insert id that you get is per session. So you get the last inserted id from your working session. There shouldn't be any problems if you use the correct method.

If you insert a row and to get the last inserted id you do a new SELECT you can run into problems as you already have predicted.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this relates to TSQL only answer rather than within C# code in the application. So within Application code I would still need to do a new SELECT even for a "scope_identity()" unless I am missing something. Perhaps a C# code example may help. Thanks.

Comment: by new select I ment to select the id of the last record inserted. Like "Select id from my_table order by created_date desc;" This can cause the problem you described. But if you use scopre_identity() you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks again, but the answer I am seeking needs to reside within C# code. So the question is if I "Select scope_identity" within my C# code, will I still be fine?

Comment: yes, if you call it from your c# code you should still be fine. To be 100% sure, you can also write your own tests. For example you can write some code that inserts records to the table non stop, and simultenously you can run another piece of code that inserts one record and gets the last record id after 1 second.