# Get Id from FirstTable that insert

Tags: sql-server

I got this example, and I need to insert (after button click) into FirstTable one row, and in RelationTable two rows. Two rows from RelationTable needs to get FirstTableId value of just inserted row for Foreign key FirstTableId.

[image]

```
INSERT INTO FirstTable(atribute) VALUES ('example');
INSERT INTO Relation(RelationDetail, SecondTableId, FirstTableId) VALUES('something', some value , ???);
INSERT INTO Relation(RelationDetail, SecondTableId, FirstTableId) VALUES('something', some value , ???);
```

Comment: Take a look at SCOPE_IDENTITY. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql or maybe the OUTPUT statement if you are inserting more than 1 row at a time in the FirstTable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS SQL Server Last Inserted ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432893/ms-sql-server-last-inserted-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql) after you do the insert:

```
DECLARE @Id INT

INSERT INTO FirstTable(atribute) VALUES ('example');
SELECT @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO Relation(RelationDetail, SecondTableId, FirstTableId) VALUES('something', some value , ???);
INSERT INTO Relation(RelationDetail, SecondTableId, FirstTableId) VALUES('something', some value , ???);
```

Comment: Do I need to put @Id instead '???' in this part - ... VALUES('something', some value, @Id) ?

Comment: Downvoter care to explain why this answer is not useful?